# Reading string from Arduino

Tags: python, python-2.5

I have an Arduino board that puts out a string like this "287, 612, 109, 1134" every second. My code tries to read this string and convert it to wind speed and wind direction. Initially it works fine but eventually on one of the readines it reads only the first number in the string which causes an error. How can I have the code get the full string and not just the first number?

```
import serial, time, csv, decimal

#for Mac
port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-A401316V'

ser = serial.Serial(port , baudrate=57600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, timeout=2)

while True:

    time.sleep(2)

    data = ser.readline( eol="\r\n").strip()

    data = data.split(',')

    if len(data) > 0:

        if data[0] != '2501':

            s = float( 1000 / float(data[0]) )

            print  'wind speed %.1f' %(round(float((2.5 * s)), 1))
            print 'wind direction', round((int(data[1]) - (50))  * .39, 0)
            print 'software version', data[2], '\n'             
        else:   
            print 'wind speed is zero'
            print 'wind direction', round((int(data[1]) - (50))  * .39, 0)
            print 'software version', data[2]

ser.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure that data read from serial port is valid (is setup of serial port on the uC-board equal to PC config)?

Comment: Yes the fourth number is a checksum and it validates correctly. The script runs fine for an hour or more until ser.readline only returns the first number in the string.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing more of the error data from the serial port, I can say that the most common reason you would see single numbers on lines (or even blank lines) is due to the non-synchronization between the Arduino program sending data to the port and your program trying to read that data. I'd wager if you print `data` after your `data=ser.readline()` and comment out the rest of the processing, you'd find lines like some of the following in the output:

```
252, 236, 218, 1136
251, 202, 215
2, 1353
199, 303, 200, 1000
259, 231, 245, 993
28
4, 144, 142, 1112
245, 199, 143, 1403

251, 19
2, 187, 1639
246, 235, 356, 1323
```

The reason for the data split across lines, or even blank lines, is that the program is trying to read data from the serial connection during or between writes. When this happens, the `readline()` gets what's available (even if partially/not written) and throws a `\n` on the end of what it found.

The fix for this is to ensure that the Arduino has finished sending data before we read, and that there is data there for us to read. A good way to handle this is with a generator that only yields lines to the main loop when they are complete (e.g. they end with a `\r\n` signifying the end of a write to the port).

```
def get_data():
    ibuffer = ""  # Buffer for raw data waiting to be processed
    while True:
        time.sleep(.1)  # Best between .1 and 1
        data = ser.read(4096)  # May need to adjust read size
        ibuffer += data  # Concat data sets that were possibly split during reading
        if '\r\n' in ibuffer:  # If complete data set
            line, ibuffer = ibuffer.split('\r\n', 1)  # Split off first completed set
            yield line.strip('\r\n')  # Sanitize and Yield data
```

The `yield` makes this function a generator you can invoke to grab the next complete set of data while keeping any thing that was split by the `read()` in a buffer to await the next `read()` where the pieces of the data set can be concatenated. Think of `yield` like a `return`, but rather than passing a value and leaving the function/loop, it passes the value and waits for `next()` to be called where it will pick up where it left off for the next pass through the loop. With this function, the rest of your program will look something like this:

```
import serial, time, csv, decimal

port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-A401316V'
ser = serial.Serial(port , baudrate=57600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, timeout=2)

def get_data():
    """
    The above function here
    """

ser_data = get_data()
while True:
    data = ser_data.next().replace(' ','').split(',')

    if len(data) > 0:
        """
        data processing down here

        """
ser.close()
```

Depending on your set up, you may want to throw a conditional in `get_data()` to break, if the serial connection is lost for example, or a `try/except` around the `data` declaration.

It's worth noting that one thing I did change aside from the aforementioned is your `ser.readline(eol)` to a byte sized `ser.read(4096)`. PySerial's `readline()` with `eol` is actually [deprecated](http://pyserial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline) with the latest versions of Python.

Hopefully this helps; or if you have more problems, hopefully it at least gives you some ideas to get on the right track.

Comment: Thanks @MikeRixWolfe for your help! I am getting the following error because I need to use 2.5;                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
File "windspeed_.py", line 19, in <module>
data = next(ser_data).replace(' ','').split(',')
NameError: name 'next' is not defined

Comment: Oh, sorry, for Python 2.5 that line would be ser_data.next().replace(' ','').split(',')

Comment: Good to hear! Be sure to mark the answer as correct